# Получение IP при запросе на сервер nodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, express, ip

У меня есть простенький express сервер, на который приходит POST-запрос '/api/checkLoginData'. Я хочу сделать, чтобы при трех запросах с ответом false с одного IP-адреса он добавлялся в массив нежелательных адресов. Как получить IP клиента?

```js
//some code

app.post('/api/checkLoginData', async (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    login: req.body.login,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  const result = await checkLoginData(user);
  if(!result) res.send(false);
  else res.send(true);
});

//some code
```

Comment: req.ip - https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ip

Comment: console.log(req.ip) // Output: ::1

Comment: правильно, это ip локалхоста, если вы попытаетесь подключиться с другого компьютера, будет нормальный ip

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ip_adress = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',').pop() ||
  req.headers["x-real-ip"] ||
  req.connection.remoteAddress ||
  req.socket.remoteAddress ||
  req.connection.socket.remoteAddress
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а пробелы лишние не убрал...